# Multi-monitor virtualisation with Parallels

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, windows

Is it possible to make a Windows 8.1 VM running on Parallels think it has two monitors but in reality these monitors are just two separate "desktops" as far as OSX is concerned running on a single real monitor?

Comment: Please let me know if this is unclear - I've only been using a Mac for 4 days!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - even in Coherence mode, which would allow you to place different Windows apps on different spaces, they have a tendency to overlap each other, depending on which was actually last in front.

I think you might have to try using Sysinternals (Microsoft) own [Desktops v2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) tool - which I haven't tested in Parallels - but this guide may help - [Unlock Virtual Desktops on Windows 7 or 8 With This Microsoft Tool](http://www.howtogeek.com/195962/unlock-virtual-desktops-on-windows-7-or-8-with-this-microsoft-tool/)